# Where can I find Cinnamon/GTK border theme named "Simple" from Mint 17.3?

Tags: themes, gtk, mint, borders

I'm desperately looking for a Cinnamon border theme from Linux Mint 17.3 named "Simple".

It looks like this: [image: Miniature]

I need this to have coherent theme in my tutorial videos.

I lost it after changing from Mint for Ubuntu. I tried installing *theme* packages from Mint 17.3 and other but with no success.

I cannot go back to Mint for various reasons, random screen flickering visible on recording being one of them.

EDIT: I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed and I also installed `cinnamon-desktop` package with probably all possible addons.

Comment: 17.10 uses wayland by default. Does the Cinnimon desktop still use gtk themes?

Comment: Yes it does. I am able to install other GTK themes but finding this specific one is a real pain.

Comment: In Debian, Cinnamon desktop installs the Mate theme package. Maybe it is there

Comment: Unfortunately - not. I've written in the question that I tried to install all default theme-related packages I could lay my hands on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67460/discussion-between-minder-and-ravery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a Metacity-only theme :/

Comment: that means it is only a windows border. Copy the theme to your themes folder. Open Look and feel and select a theme to customize. In the widows tab you should see the border theme